# Toggle letter case -- exclude custom words from a list

Tags: words, capitalization

Xah Lee wrote (some time ago) the following function that toggles the letter-case of the selected region or the current word.  When toggling to initial caps, some words should not be capitalized such as `and`, `or`, `for`, and perhaps some custom words like `to`.

**Q**:  How can `toggle-letter-case` be modified to exclude select words (e.g., from a list of custom words) when making *initial caps*.

**Scenario #1 -- all uppercase**:  FOO TO BAR FOR BAZ; AND, APPLE TO ORANGE

**Scenario #2 -- all lowercase**:  foo to bar for baz; and, apple to orange

**Initial Caps -- Desired Result**:  Foo to Bar for Baz; and, Apple to Orange

```lisp
(defun toggle-letter-case ()
  "Toggle the letter case of current word or text selection.
  Toggles between: “all lower”, “Init Caps”, “ALL CAPS”."
(interactive)
  (let ((deactivate-mark nil)
        (case-fold-search nil)
        p1 p2)
   (if (region-active-p)
       (setq p1 (region-beginning) p2 (region-end))
     (let ((bds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
       (setq p1 (car bds) p2 (cdr bds))))
   (when (not (eq last-command this-command))
     (save-excursion
       (goto-char p1)
       (cond
        ((looking-at "[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "all lower"))
        ((looking-at "[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]") (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
        ((looking-at "[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "init caps"))
        ((looking-at "[[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "all lower"))
        ((looking-at "[[:upper:]]") (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
        (t (put this-command 'state "all lower")))))
   (cond
    ((string= "all lower" (get this-command 'state))
     (upcase-initials-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "init caps"))
    ((string= "init caps" (get this-command 'state))
     (upcase-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
    ((string= "all caps" (get this-command 'state))
     (downcase-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "all lower")))))
```

Comment: The code is a bit weird. Why do you test `region-active-p` after already having tested it and thrown an error if `nil`? Why `let*` if there are no binding dependencies? And it's not clear what all that stuff about *Form Interrogatory Number 17.1* is for.

Comment: As for the question itself: You already check what you are looking at. Why can't you also check whether it is one of your stop words and take the appropriate action?

Comment: @Drew -- Cleaning up the code is always a good thing.  My only idea as to a potential solution to the main issue was to run a `replace-regexp` (with word boundaries) that `mapc` down the list one by one *after* running `upcace-initials-region` on the entire selected region.

Comment: In the initial question (before the edit), I had picked a real-life example that came up today while working in the home-office, but the example has now been changed to be more programming-like.  :)  The first example is all uppercase, the second example is all lowercase, and the third example is the desired result.

Comment: I'd write a function `capitalize-region-except`, which proceeds as you suggested, but using `regexp-opt` instead of `mapc`.  Then you can clean-up the posted function, which has multiple problems, and incorporate your written function as a 4th case or replace the current capitalize one.

Comment: @politza -- I had trouble figuring out how to use `regexp-opt` with word-boundaries, so I just used `mapconcat` and `rx-to-string`.  The other problem I had was because `case-fold-search` was set to `nil` at the outset of the function, but needed to be set to `t` when doing the search and replace.  I did not understand how to create a 4th category, so I just modified the initial-caps category.  I had initially contemplated replacing individual matches with specific words, instead of `downcase` the match, but your comment led me to believe that is what you had intended.

Comment: What's wrong with `(regexp-opt WORDS 'words)` ?

Comment: @politza -- thank you -- I've updated the draft answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @politza for `(regexp-opt WORDS 'words)`

```lisp
(defun toggle-letter-case ()
"Initially written by Xah Lee, and slightly modified by @lawlist.
Toggle the letter case of current word or text selection.
Toggles between: “all lower”, “Init Caps”, “ALL CAPS”.
As to initial-capitals, do not capitalize hard-coded list of words."
(interactive)
  (let ((deactivate-mark nil)
        (case-fold-search nil)
        (regexp-exclusion (regexp-opt '("and" "for" "or" "to") 'words))
        p1 p2)
   (if (region-active-p)
       (setq p1 (region-beginning) p2 (region-end))
     (let ((bds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
       (setq p1 (car bds) p2 (cdr bds))) )
   (when (not (eq last-command this-command))
     (save-excursion
       (goto-char p1)
       (cond
        ((looking-at "[[:lower:]][[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "all lower"))
        ((looking-at "[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]") (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
        ((looking-at "[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "init caps"))
        ((looking-at "[[:lower:]]") (put this-command 'state "all lower"))
        ((looking-at "[[:upper:]]") (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
        (t (put this-command 'state "all lower")))))
   (cond
    ((string= "all lower" (get this-command 'state))
      (upcase-initials-region p1 p2)
      (put this-command 'state "init caps")
      (let ((case-fold-search t))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char p1)
            (while (re-search-forward regexp-exclusion p2 t)
              (replace-match (downcase (match-string 0)) t)))))
    ((string= "init caps" (get this-command 'state))
     (upcase-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "all caps"))
    ((string= "all caps" (get this-command 'state))
     (downcase-region p1 p2) (put this-command 'state "all lower")))))
```

Comment: It looks to me like the first two cases in the `cond` are not required, because they are subsets of cases 4 and 5. So the code could be simplified by removing them. And the last case 6 seem redundant too, unless there is a possibility of not looking at a letter at all. If it was me, I would try removing cases 1 and 2, swapping cases 4 and 5, turn the new 5 into a "t" case, and delete case 6. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's this command maybe you've seen?

It doesn't toggle, but rather just Init case with a list of words of exceptions.

```
(defun xah-title-case-region-or-line (*begin *end)
  "Title case text between nearest brackets, or current line, or text selection.
Capitalize first letter of each word, except words like {to, of, the, a, in, or, and, …}. If a word already contains cap letters such as HTTP, URL, they are left as is.

When called in a elisp program, *begin *end are region boundaries.
URL `http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_title_case_text.html'
Version 2015-05-07"
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (let (
           -p1
           -p2
           (-skipChars "^\"<>(){}[]“”‘’‹›«»「」『』【】〖〗《》〈〉〔〕"))
       (progn
         (skip-chars-backward -skipChars (line-beginning-position))
         (setq -p1 (point))
         (skip-chars-forward -skipChars (line-end-position))
         (setq -p2 (point)))
       (list -p1 -p2))))
  (let* (
         (-strPairs [
                     [" A " " a "]
                     [" And " " and "]
                     [" At " " at "]
                     [" As " " as "]
                     [" By " " by "]
                     [" Be " " be "]
                     [" Into " " into "]
                     [" In " " in "]
                     [" Is " " is "]
                     [" It " " it "]
                     [" For " " for "]
                     [" Of " " of "]
                     [" Or " " or "]
                     [" On " " on "]
                     [" Via " " via "]
                     [" The " " the "]
                     [" That " " that "]
                     [" To " " to "]
                     [" Vs " " vs "]
                     [" With " " with "]
                     [" From " " from "]
                     ["'S " "'s "]
                     ]))
    (save-excursion 
      (save-restriction
        (narrow-to-region *begin *end)
        (upcase-initials-region (point-min) (point-max))
        (let ((case-fold-search nil))
          (mapc
           (lambda (-x)
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (while
                 (search-forward (aref -x 0) nil t)
               (replace-match (aref -x 1) 'FIXEDCASE 'LITERAL)))
           -strPairs))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- I'll be able to test it out later this evening -- greatly appreciated.  I enjoy using your functions, and reading the tutorials on your website.  :)

Comment: @lawlist thank you for using and mentioning my site, i love it!